# Azure PowerShell deployment script runs extremely slowly and lacks configuration options

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm

The following script runs okay, I can see it doing the designed task (deploying 500 virtual machines) but I get a warning from New-AzVM that tells me that it's using the most sane storage account that it can reach. I've been having a lot of problems with the virtual machines that it spins up, and they are spinning up very slowly (at a speed of about 10 per hour) and I was wondering if the problem might be that I'm unable to designate a storage account as part of the configuration.

I've done quite a few google searches, looking through the microsoft documentation on these scripts, and haven't found a way to specify the configuration I want.

The script I'm using is this:

```
$rgn = "VolumetricTest"
$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$logincred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("xadminx",$passwd)
$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name volumetric-vnet -ResourceGroupName VolumetricTest 
$loc = "East US"
$nsg_rdp_in = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -name "RDP_in" -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 300 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 3389 -Access Allow
$nsg_rdp_out = New-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -name "RDP_out" -Protocol Tcp -Direction Outbound -Priority 301 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 3389 -Access Allow

$suffixes = @()

1..500 | ForEach-Object { $nm = $_.ToString("000"); $suffixes += @("$nm") } 

Foreach ( $suffix in $suffixes) {
    Write-Host $suffix
    $vmname = "SCLD-VT-W$suffix"
    Write-Host $vmname
    $nsg = New-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "nsgW$suffix" -ResourceGroupName VolumetricTest -Location 'East US' -SecurityRules $nsg_rdp_in 
    Write-Host $nsg.Id 
    $net = New-AzNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -name "WNetAddr$suffix" -Subnet $( Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name default -VirtualNetwork $vnet ) -Primary
    $nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "WNetif$suffix" -ResourceGroupName VolumetricTest -Location 'East US' -IpConfiguration $net -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id 
    Write-Host $nic.Id 
    $vmconfig = New-AzVMConfig -VMName $vmname -VMSize "Standard_B2s" | Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $vmname -Credential $logincred | Set-AzVMSourceImage -PublisherName "microsoftwindowsdesktop" -Offer "Windows-10" -skus 'rs1-enterprise' -Version latest | Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id
    New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgn -Location "East US" -VM $vmconfig
}
```

(details replaced with filler of course)

results like:

```
014
SCLD-VT-W014
/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000/resourceGroups/VolumetricTest/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/nsgW014
/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000/resourceGroups/VolumetricTest/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/WNetif014
WARNING: Since the VM is created using premium storage or managed disk, existing standard storage account, volumetrictestbootdiag, is used for boot diagnostics.
```

This machine was created in about 2 minutes.

Some machines seem to take less than a minute to spin up, while others take upwards of 10.

It selects the proper storage account I want to use, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a VM if you enable diagnostics you have to specify a storage account. In this case if you doesn't specify a SA it will create a storage account for you or select any existing storage account.

You could use [Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmbootdiagnostics?view=azurermps-6.13.0) to modifies boot diagnostics properties of a virtual machine to specify the storage configuration.

```
Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics -VM $VM -Enable -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -StorageAccountName "DiagnosticStorage"
```